# Using shell script to pull strings out of a config file

Tags: shell

Let's say I have a PHP file such as this:

```
<?php
/* Comments */

define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');

/* More comments */

define('DB_NAME', 'dbname');
define('DB_USER', 'etc');

/* etc...*/
?>
```

How can I use shell script only to pull the variable values for DB_SERVER, DB_NAME, etc and store them in variables to use within the shell script? (/bin/sh, not bash)

Answer (score 5):

```
# with /bin/bash
. <(awk '/define/ {print $2"="$4}' FS="'" foo.php)    
# with /bin/sh
declare `awk '/define/ {print $2"="$4}' FS="'" foo.php`
```

Result

```
echo $DB_SERVER # localhost
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/9cb0eb6/ff-audio.sh#L97)

Comment: Modified to grab only DB_ vars: `. <(awk '/define.*DB_/{print...`